# jQuery .load() and CDN files

Tags: jquery

I want to load the same header and footer files for multiple html pages using jQuery .load().

According to best practices, I should link my scripts in the footer.  But, problem is, if the link to the jQuery CDN files is in my footer, then the .load() function will never run because the footer file will never get loaded.

The only way is to link the jQuery CDN files in the head section.  But then, I have to do that on every html page, which I don't want to.

Is there a solution to this?

PS: I don't want to use php server-side includes.